# SQL Select Where Join Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way to do a select to do something like the following without running two queries? The first query gets the "id" of the a column and the second queries another table returning where that "id" matches?

```
SELECT `name` 
FROM `attributes` 
INNER JOIN `attribute_vals` 
ON `attributes`.`id`=`attribute_vals`.`attr_id`
WHERE `name`='weight'
```

Thank you for your answers!

Just a quick graphical representation of what I am trying to achieve!

[image]

Comment: The `join` clause should come before the `where` clause. Other than that, do you have another  problem?

Comment: First query? Second query? I only see *one* (malformed) query.

Comment: that should have thrown you a syntax error

Comment: Yes it did. Just trying out how to fix it. Thank you

Comment: Here's a nice guide on JOINS http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins that I'm sure you'll learn a lot from ;-)

Comment: Great link, thank you!

Comment: Another syntax error in your query - make sure your back-ticks don't encompass the dots.  Each entity name (e.g. table, column) should be surrounded with back-ticks.

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors in the question - now you can look to the answers for solutions to your actual problem (aggregation).

Comment: Can you show an example of what is in the tables and what result you expect?

Comment: I just added a picture to the question!

Comment: @JoshuaWieczorek I updated my answer to address the additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a few assumptions about your DB design:

1. the `name` column is in the `attributes` table,
2. the `attr_id, name` combination is unique, and
3. there's a `val` column in the `attribute_vals` table.

It sounds like you want a simple join limiting the values table by the name in the attributes table.

You can then get associated `attribute_vals` data in a single query.

```
SELECT
    `av`.`id`,
    `av`.`attribute_id`,
    `av`.`value`
FROM `attributes` AS `a`
INNER JOIN `attribute_vals` AS `av`
    ON `a`.`id`=`av`.`attr_id`
WHERE `a`.`name`= 'weight'
```

Answer (score 0):

This query gets you all attribute values for the attribute 'weight'. Is this what you want?

```
select *
from attribute_vals
where attribute_id in (select id from attributes where name= 'weight');
```

Comment: That is exactly what is needed. Thank you.